# Invalid Schema on Confluent Controlcenter

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api, confluent-control-center

I am just trying to set up a Value-Schema for a Topic in the Web interface of Confluent Control Center.
I chose the Avro-format and tried the following schema:

```
{
  "fields": [
    {"name":"date",
     "type":"dates",
     "doc":"Date of the count"
    },
    {"name":"time",
     "type":"timestamp-millis",
     "doc":"date in ms"
    },
    {"name":"count",
     "type":"int",
     "doc":"Number of Articles"
    }
  ],
  "name": "articleCount",
  "type": "record"
}
```

But the interface keeps on saying the input schema is invalid.
I have no idea why.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are issues related to datatypes.

1. `"type":"dates"` => `"type": "string"`
2. `"type":"timestamp-millis"` => `"type": {"type": "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"}`

Updated schema will be like:

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "date",
      "type": "string",
      "doc": "Date of the count"
    },
    {
      "name": "time",
      "type": {
        "type": "long",
        "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
      },
      "doc": "date in ms"
    },
    {
      "name": "count",
      "type": "int",
      "doc": "Number of Articles"
    }
  ],
  "name": "articleCount",
  "type": "record"
}
```

Sample Payload:

```
{
    "date": "2020-07-10",
    "time": 12345678900,
    "count": 1473217
}
```

More reference related to Avro datatypes can be found here:

- https://docs.oracle.com/database/nosql-12.1.3.0/GettingStartedGuide/avroschemas.html